# How to edit user (even password) with SpringSecurity Core and UI in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

my goal is to create an edit page where the user can change his data.

this is my _form:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'firstName', 'error')} required">
<label for="firstName">
<g:message code="userSec.firstName.label" default="First Name" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="firstName" required="" value="${user?.firstName}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'lastName', 'error')} required">
<label for="lastName">
<g:message code="userSec.lastName.label" default="Last Name" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="lastName" required="" value="${user?.lastName}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'username', 'error')} required">
<label for="username">
<g:message code="userSec.username.label" default="Username" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="username" required="" value="${user?.username}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'email', 'error')} required">
<label for="email">
<g:message code="userSec.email.label" default="Email" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:field type="email" name="email" required="" value="${user?.email}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: command, field: 'password', 'error')} required">
<label for="password"> 
<g:message code="user.password.label" default="Password" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:field type="password" name="password" class="passwd" required="" value="${command.password}" />
<span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: command, field: 'password2', 'error')} required">
<label for="password2"> 
<g:message code="user.password2.label" default="Password (again)" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:field type="password" name="password2" required="" value="${command.password2}" />
</div>
```

and this is my edit page:

```
<%@ page import="p2s.UserSec" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'userSec.label', default: 'UserSec')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#edit-userSec" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
<div class="nav" role="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="edit-userSec" class="content scaffold-edit" role="main">
<h1><g:message code="default.edit.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
<div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
<g:hasErrors bean="${user}">
<ul class="errors" role="alert">
<g:eachError bean="${user}" var="error">
<li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
</g:eachError>
</ul>
</g:hasErrors>
<g:form url="[resource:user, action:'update']" method="PUT" >
<g:hiddenField name="version" value="${user?.version}" />
<fieldset class="form">
<g:render template="form"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttons">
<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
</fieldset>
</g:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I let the user modify his data? I've got many trouble with the password because i can't decode it and match it with the password that the user give me when he want to change it.

I'd like to use Spring method to do this.

Thanks to all, sorry if this is a easy question but I'm new to Grails.

Comment: You don't decode the existing password, you hash the new one and match the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't display the old password, even with * characters, since it's hashed and in general useless. Give them an empty password field, and if you want to make them type it twice add a second and add a validation error if they don't match.

You don't need to worry if the password has changed. If they re-enter the same password as before, it will has to the same hash (or in bcrypt an equivalent hash) and that field won't be considered modified. As long as they're already authenticated you shouldn't care whether they change it or not.